# How to send updated state variable to another component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

> Example code:

```
export default function Cart() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
    // Stores the selected image URI 
    const [file, setFile] = useState(''); 

    // Stores any error message 
    const [error, setError] = useState(null); 

    // Function to pick an image from 
    //the device's media library 
    const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    }); 

    if (!result.canceled) {
      console.log(result);
   
      setFile(result.assets[0].uri);
    } else {
      alert('You did not select any image.');
    }
  };
 

  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>pickImageAsync() } style={styles.btnContainer} ><View><Text style={styles.textview}>Upload Image</Text>
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

            {/* Conditionally render the image 
            or error message */}  
            {file ? navigation.navigate('AddToCart',{'file':file}): ( 
                // Display an error message if there's 
                // an error or no image selected 
                <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text> 
            )}  
    </View>   
    
  );
}
```

> I am using ImagePicker library to send over an image to another screen
> with screen navigator. It is stored in a state variable. However it is
> giving me an error that it cannot update a component while rendering
> another component. I am having to pass the same imagefile to multiple
> components from one to another. I have just one upload button and upon
> selecting , needs to send over the image to another component, which I
> am acquiring through route.params.
>
> I realize that it cannot update the image and send at the same time,
> how do I work around this

Comment: add this logic {file ? navigation.navigate('AddToCart',{'file':file}): ( 
                // Display an error message if there's 
                // an error or no image selected 
                <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text> 
            )}   in the pickImageAsync function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the above but the data (image uri)does not get sent over in the first onPress as I assume the state is not updated yet (one step behind). If i go back and change the image , the image I uploaded previously renders and updates then. Any idea how to update on single pass when setFile is called

Comment: do the navigation part with a useeffect(()=>{if (file!=='')navigation.navigate('AddToCart',{'file':file}),[file]}

Answer (score 0):

this is a bad approach, will recommend you to do the navigation on some action, in your case can be when just when you got the file from picker and if don't have file update error text

```
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  // Stores the selected image URI 
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');

  // Stores any error message 
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // Function to pick an image from 
  //the device's media library 
  const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    });

    //todo set error if don't have file
    if (!result.canceled) {
      console.log(result);
      setFile(result.assets[0].uri); 
      navigation.navigate('AddToCart',{'file': result.assets[0].uri})

    } else {
      alert('You did not select any image.');
    }
  };


  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>pickImageAsync() } style={styles.btnContainer} >
      
      <View><Text style={styles.textview}>Upload Image</Text>
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

            {!file  ? <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text> : null}

    </View>   
    
  );

}
```

And All Set!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the above but the data (image uri)does not get sent over in the first onPress as I assume the state is not updated yet (one step behind). If i go back and change the image , the image I uploaded previously renders and updates then. Any idea how to update on single pass when setFile is called

Comment: sorry my bad, changing my answer little bit, send the file directly to next page